# JQuery (Javascript) CSS Value & Operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I need to get the CSS value Width of a DIV-Container.
Then I will divide this width value through 245px.

Pseudo Code:

```
var articles = "#showroom ul" css width / 245px
```

Comment: Check out "visual jQuery."  It's a pleasant, fast way to browse jQuery for functions like width().  http://api.jquery.com/visual/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the `width` function:

```
var articles = $('#showroom ul').width() / 245;
```

[jQuery `width()` function.](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 0):

for more specific dimensions see the [dimension-functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) in the jQuery manual

`.outerWidth()` and `.outerWidth(true)` are usefull in particular for elements with margins and borders

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific needs, its worth mentioning the outerWidth() function.  As it will return the width of the element, along with left and right padding, border, and optionally margin, in pixels.

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: Cool. Thank you for this additional info.